# Does the statement "there exists a set such that.." allows an empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

In my note, I have written a statement in the following form

"If there exists a subset $\mathcal{D} \subseteq \mathcal{W}$ such that....., then property $A$ holds".

In some cases, I need $\mathcal{D}$ to be an empty set such that $A$ holds. Thus, I am wondering if my statement "There exists a subset (or a set) $\mathcal{D}$" already allows the case where $\mathcal{D}$ is an empty set.

I personally think so because an empty set is a subset of any set.

Comment: Yes: the *empty* set is a set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, standard notation allows $\mathcal D=\emptyset$ within the possibility of the restricted quantification $\exists \mathcal D\subseteq \mathcal W,[\cdots]$.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not have to assume that $D$ was a non-empty set to obtain your result $A$, then it will automatically hold for empty $D$ as well.

If you did have to assume that $D$ was a non-empty set to obtain your result $A$, then you will also have to consider the case of $D$ being empty--a proof by cases.